# How do I get list of files installed for a plugin in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

If you download an archive (ZIP file) for an eclipse plugin package (different versions in the same archive), the contents are usually the following:

- features
- plugins
- artifacts.xml
- content.xml

If the installation of a plugin A version X has resulted in the copy of certain jars to 
`eclipse folder\features` and `eclipse folder\plugins` folder, is there any way I can a list of these jars, so I can separate them for a specific version for local backup?

Answer (score 0):

Look deeper in the zip file.  "features" and "plugins" are folders.

Comment: what I meant was, if the zip contains jars for multiple versions and during installation, if I select version X, how do I determine which jars were copied for the same?